# Detecting DllImportAttribute and its data in an assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, clr

I am trying to find (at runtime) the the the p/invokes along with their information: 1) Dll name 2) EntryPoint.

I tried something like this: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributesData();` but for some reason I dont see the type `DllImportAttribute` listed there although I have a p/invoke in that assembly.

I am pretty sure am missing something here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pinvokes = from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
               from method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
               let dllImport = (DllImportAttribute)method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DllImportAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault()
               where dllImport != null
               select new
               {
                   DllName = dllImport.Value,
                   EntryPoint = dllImport.EntryPoint,
               };
```